# Is this citation proper MLA?

Tags: mla

I am using a source for a paper and this was the MLA citation given at the end of the source. Yet, I don't think that it is actually MLA.

Shouldn't the format be **Last Name, First Name** so on....

Here it is

**Robert Bennett, in an essay for Novels for Students, Gale, 1997.**

Thanks!

Comment: This question is off-topic here. You might like to try the [writers.se] site.

Comment: MLA and other style guide questions are off-topic at ELU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct - it is not in the right format for an MLA citation and **should** be *Last Name, First Name*. This [image](http://www.newpaltz.k12.ny.us/cms/lib/NY01000611/Centricity/Domain/305/MLA_citations__Quick_Look.jpg) may be of assistance.

Comment: Thanks! I went back through and edited each source to match the MLA format.